# State Monad never ends

Tags: haskell, state

Could somone please tell me why does this piece of code which uses the State monad never end?

```
fib' :: State [Int] ()
fib' = do l <- get
          let l2 = sum (last2 l)
          put (l ++ [l2])
          return ()
          fib'

take 10 $ execState fib' [0, 1]
```

When I execute it in the ghci REPL, the function executes without stopping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing here is more or less equivalent to the following:

```
rfib (last:last':rest) = let new = last + last' in rfib (new:last:last':rest)
```

which attempts to create the numbers in reverse order "lazily". (The order doesn't really matter, I just did it in reverse to get rid of the distracting (++) and last2).

But the point is, you **never** compute a list, as the type checker will tell you.
For example, the follwoing are all well typed:

```
res1 = (take 10 . rfib) [1,0] :: [Int]   
res2 = (take 10 . snd . rfib) [1,0] :: [Int]   
res3 = (take 10 . snd . snd . rfib) [1,0] :: [Int]   
res4 = "foo" == rfib [1,0]
```

Sometimes it is a **good idea** to not write annotations, you know.
Then you would see that something like this was inferred:

```
rfib :: Num a => [a] -> b
```

which corresponds closely to the principal type of your foo':

```
fib' :: Num a => State [a] b
```

And this type should you make think a bit. It the case of `rfib` it tells that out of nowhere you create a value of any type you want, here called `b`.
And this is synonymous for "there is no such value". Like in `head []` or `unJust Nothing` or `error "Bottom"`, any attempt to nevertheless compute that value must diverge.

Matters are different when the fresh type variable that appears in the result is "protected" by a type constructor. Then what happens will depend on the type, whose constructor is applied. As it stands, it works with Writer, but not with State. Still, such an unexpected type should make one think the case over.

Comment: Not quite true. If you take his recursive, neverending code but put it in the writer monad to get something of type `fib [0,1] :: MonadWriter [Int] m => m b`, then `take 10 $ execWriter (fib [0,1])` works just fine, despite the `b` in the return type. So his overall attempt was not as broken as you suggest, it was just the wrong monad.

Comment: This is quite different, @JoachimBreitner, because then the type `m` appears left from the => arrow and hence does not come out of nowhere.  It is clear that a new type variable that is protected by a constructor does not signal undefined'ness, as in `Nothing :: Maybe u` and likewise `Monad m => m u` is just fine.

Comment: At one point, you say that the list is never computed. Let us assume I was the one writing `rfib`. Let us also assume that I am taking one final look at the body of `rfib` to confirm what I have written is correct before jumping into the ghci prompt to test `rfib`. Now, could you please tell me, what piece of information would have made me realize that the computation of rfib will never converge?

Comment: @Ingo, `m` is not the relevant type variable; the `b` is. I should have written `fib [0,1] :: Writer [Int] b`; now the analogy to the type `fib' :: Num a => State [a] b` is complete.

Comment: @Jay The fact that its type is what I told above, which makes all of the four examples `res1` to `res4` well typed. Doesn't the latter look strange?

Comment: @Ingo The type `rfib :: Num a => [a] -> b` does look strange considering I'm expecting a list and not a type variable like `b`. But I realize this only after checking for the type. What I was asking was, what bit of info, had I known, would have helped me to avoid writing rfib the way I have, in the first place. There is obviously something that you know about the process, haskell uses to evaluate an arbitrary piece of code. And If I could understand that underlying bit of info, I think I would be able to look at a piece of code and determine if it will converge or diverge...hope am  not confu

Comment: @JoachimBreitner Yes, I see that you're right in this respect. The point is that in both cases (State and Writer) the `b` appears protected by a type constructor, hence it is not alarming in the same way as with `rfib`. Will correct my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Jay You assume too much about my knowledge. I am just proposing to write some code, check the type and make sure one understands it, especially when some unexpected type variables show up in the result type. In the case of `rfib`, the type clearly tells you that `rfib`will not terminate. Then you can figure out why, and find, for example, that there is no base case for the recursion. Matters are not that easy when the unknown type appears as argument in a type application, here, termination is possible, in principle, but dangers are looming, like in `(undefined, undefined)`

Comment: @Jay I forgot to mention that this valuable information one can read from the type is lost when you start out with a type annotation, like `rfib :: [Int -> [Int]`, because the typechecker is perfectly happy with it, and you think: the type checker was silent, so it must be ok. That being said, I am far from advocating to avoid type annotations always. But if you have a feeling that somehow you don't fully understand your code and how it's supposed to work, it can help to give it a try without annotations.

Answer (score 8):

The result of `execState` is the value of the state at the end of the computation. But your computation never ends: `fib'` calls `fib'`. While in your case it would be possible to prove that the first 10 elements of the state eventually do not change, the compiler is not able to predict that (nor should it).

You might want to check out the Writer Monad, where you can process the written data lazily.

Comment: I am using Control.Monad.State.Lazy. Even though fib' goes on endlessly, wouldn't it only execute as much is necessary? If I simply put execState fib' [0,1] on a line then I would understand that the computation might go on forever. But shouldn't take 10 $ execState fib' [0, 1] return just enough to satisfy the request considering Haskell is lazy?

Comment: Lazyness cannot do magic. Even once `fib` has recursed a few times, there is no way to know that a later call to `fib` might not state the change to something completely different. Note that you *always* set the *whole* state; the fact that you happen to use `l ++ something` there is just a speciality of your particular program.

Comment: @Jay, look at my answer which tells you how you could have known that it wouldn't terminate without even running it.

Answer (score 4):

`return` does not work like it does in imperative languaues. It is defined differently for each monad, for the state monad, it is defined as:
        `return x = State $ \s -> (x,s)`

So it doesn't actually break out of the `fib'` function, but instead binds a new State monad to the rest of the computation.

**EDIT:**

While my original answer is true, it does not answer the OP's question. In the OP's code, `return` acts as a no-op. For the reason why the OP's code never terminates, see other answers. I am still leaving my answer here because I feel it is still something important to point out, given that `return` did show up unnecessarily in the OP's code sample

Answer (score 4):

1. `return ()` line is redundant and can be removed
2. `(++)` is almost always a bad idea as it's O(N) in the size of its first argument.
3. You construct *many* lists of increasing length, while your goal is construct a single infinite list

Answer (score 1):

At @Joachim Breitner's suggestion, a possible solution using the lazy Writer monad would be:

```hs
import Control.Monad.Writer

fib' :: Writer [Int] ()
fib' = tell [1, 1] >> go 1 1
    where
        go :: Int -> Int -> Writer [Int] ()
        go f1 f2 = do
            let f3 = f1 + f2
            tell [f3]
            go f2 f3

main = print $ take 10 $ execWriter fib'
```